# Error when loading APA6 citation style with documentclass elsarticle

Tags: biblatex, natbib, elsarticle, apa6

I am working on an article to be published in a journal from Elsevier and that requires the apa6 citation style and format. In my file, I am doing that just with the following commands:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex}
```

Even though the results on the document are the ones expected, I get the following error while compiling:

```
l.155 \blx@packageincompatibility
                                 
The 'natbib' package and biblatex are incompatible.
```

I struggle to understand the source of the problem. I tried to use other packages (like apacite) but nothing worked until now.

Did anybody else ever encounter this issue before?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Do you absolutely require biblatex (and biber), or will a solution based on the apacite package and bib style do? (The apacite package implements V6 o the APA formatting guidelines.) Please advise.

Comment: Double-check what the journal submission guidelines have to say about LaTeX submissions. It is fairly unlikely that the publisher would want a `biblatex` submission, since their document class essentially hard-codes `natbib` and `biblatex` and `natbib` require different (post-processing) workflows. It is entirely possible that your may be prepared with one of the supplied BibTeX styles even if that does not exactly match APA style - sometimes the exact citation/bibliography style is only applied before publishing by journal staff.

Answer (score 2):

The `elsarticle` class is not really compatible with `biblatex`.

The class provides the `nonatbib` option, but it's incomplete on this regard and uses `natbib` things even if the option is issued.

Fixes:

```
% we need to provide something to fool the setting of \bibsep
\newdimen\bibsep
%%%

\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn,nonatbib]{elsarticle}

% biblatex wants to do \newcounter{author} and \newcommand{\bibfont}
\expandafter\let\csname c@author\endcsname\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
%%%

\usepackage[style=apa6]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{angenendt}

\cite{cotton}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following solution makes use of the fact that the `apacite` citation management package and associated bib style implement version 6 of the APA formatting guidelines for bibliographies and use BibTeX to do so. Observe that one has to run `\newlength\bibsep` *before* `\documentclass` and employ `nonatbib` option.

[image]

```
\newlength\bibsep % minor kludge
\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn,nonatbib]{elsarticle} 

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{ao:3001,
  author = {Alpha and Omega},
  title  = {Thoughts},
  year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\cite{ao:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```