# Anyone knows how to show DOI or URL in \bibliographystyle{apa}?

Tags: pdftex, apa-style, elsarticle, bibliographystyle

I have followed the approach in the following link:

> https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-misc-apa/

However, I want my reference lists to follow APA 7th ed. DOI is not generated at the end of each citation although the bib file contains DOI info.

Comment: Given that the `apa.bst` from that link is from 1992!! And does not mention DOI or URL at all, it is no surprise.  You'll probably have to find some style that implements apa 7th edition.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527526/263192

Comment: Tried this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638127/269060, But apacite does not produce APA 7. I think biblatex-apa is not a solution for me since I'm working with elsarticle class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use biblatex-apa for this purpose. I think that's the only implementation of APA 7 edition as of now.
If you are using Zotero citation manager software, it can generate APA 7 bibliography. In order to insert citations from Zotero, you will also need one add-on for Zotero, called Better Bibtex.
After you finish your drafting of the document, export the whole bibliography from Zotero in a .bib file into the directory where your tex file is saved. If you have written
`\bibliography{references.bib}` in your document, save this .bib as references.bib in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding ZOTERO ! 
However, that does not solve the problem. I get the following error while using biblatex-apa : "Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'. \blx@packageincompatibility"